# How to set Google Adsense Targetable Ad Placements in a website that has several language versions?

Tags: google-adsense

My site is translated into 8 different languages (english, spanish, portuguese, german, french, italian, dutch and russian). All language versions of the website share the same Adsense data-ad-slot ID.

When trying to set a new custom channel as a targetable ad placement, there is an obligatory field called **Site language**.

[image]

Do i have to create custom channels as a targetable ad placements for **each** language? If not, how will the advertiser know the exact language version in which their ads will be displayed on?

I really don't want to end up creating a new ad unit for each language and size (i use 728x90, 160x600 and 336x280). That would mean having 24 ad units instead of just 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will target the ad toward the language of the page, the site, the user, and the advertiser: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2753586?hl=en

This is a good question however! I can see hesitating creating 24 channels though that may be a great idea(!) for the advertiser and you may (likely) get better bids on these channels. You can, I assume, use the description section for this too, however, I still think that separate channels is the best idea even though it is more work. It may be a price you want to pay for better ad placement, bids, and ad CTR (click-through rates). It sounds like a win win win to me.

Comment: Great feedback. Yeah, i'm thinking it'ill be better to create channels for each language case. May I ask an additional question since it seems you know more about the targetable ads? If a custom channel is assigned to 2 different same-size ads (i need 2 because there are 2 different color schemes), will the advertiser bid per custom channel or per one of those 2 ads?

Comment: @andufo I am not the expert- I just have been going through some of the same things lately. They can only big on the channel as far as I know. I am not sure they can see color themes when they bid- I would bet not. If you think this is important info, you can try a test and mention the color theme difference in the description and see what you get. I do not think I would work this hard though. I would think that ad sizes and placement (language too) would be more important.